# Better data-structure design

Tags: database, data-structures, recursion

Currently in my application I have a single table that is giving me a bit of trouble. The issue at hand is I have a value object that is mapped to this table. When the data is returned to me as an array of value objects, I have to then loop through this array and begin my recursion by matching the ParentID to parent ObjectID's.

The column ParentID is either null (acts a parent) or it holds the value of an ObjectID.

I know there has to be a better way to create this data structure so that I do not have to do recursive loops to match ParentID's with their ObjectID's.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Here is the table in describe form:

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| ObjectID       | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| ObjectHeight   | decimal(6,2)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| ObjectWidth    | decimal(6,2)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| ObjectX        | decimal(6,2)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| ObjectY        | decimal(6,2)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| ObjectLabel    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| TemplateID     | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| ObjectTypeID   | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| ParentID       | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| CreationDate   | datetime         | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| LastModifyDate | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+e
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? If so, SQL Server 2005 has constructs for dealing with hierarchical data structures. You can create a Common Table Expression to query in a recursive fashion.

Comment: I am not using SQL Server, I have used CTE's before. I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested set model. See the very good explanation here: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: The issue with this example, is that I am limited to the number of children that I select. In my current development, I need to maintain the concept that any parent can have an infinite number of children.

Comment: @Tempname: Hmmmm... I don't get the problem sorry. You can use a nested set with an infinite amount of children. I've not used it with more than 100-150 items, but I don't see why you couldn't.